# Loading certain amount of item per page using jinja

Tags: javascript, html, flask, pagination, jinja2

I'm using Flask and a simple pagination class that learnt from [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/44/) and got it working with fixed `page_size`;

Now I want to load certain amount of items based on the browser window size.

For example: `item_count = window_height/item_height;`

If it can be done this way or if I have to write javascript to handle pagination myself?